# Styling (unknown) children of ControlTemplate Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-style

i'm having a problem with WPF/Xaml styles right now:

I'm trying to create a generalized button that can show either text or a path icon. The path should change its "Fill"-Property when the button is hovered.

My current approach allows using a control templates resources to style the path with a color, but i can't change it when the mouse hoveres the button. The current style code looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border
                    x:Name="Border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Padding="2">
                    <ContentPresenter
                            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Path}}">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Foreground}" />
                    </Style>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">

                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HoveredDarkBackgroundBrush}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#d0d0d0" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">

                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBackgroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#c4c4c4" />
</Style>
```

I understand that i need to change the color in the control templates triggers, but i don't understand how to apply the color to the path.
Can someone give me some hints or a path to the solution?

Regards
Felix

PS.:
The styled button looks like this:

```
<Button ToolTip="...">
    <Path Data="..." />
</Button>
```

Comment: I think the problem is with `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Path}`, take that out and it appears to work as you wish.

Comment: Okay, i got the solution: I removed the BasedOn and changed the RelativeSource to Self with a Path of Parent.Foreground